# Is it legal to 3D print your own firearms?

Tags: united-states, firearms

Lets say Bob wants to 3D print his own firearms that are not considered NFA items.

- Is it legal for Bob to 3d print his own firearms?
- Is it legal for Bob to gift the 3d printed firearm to his son?
- Is it legal for Bob to sell his 3d printed firearm via a private transaction?

Comment: Laws on private transfers vary greatly by state.

Comment: Adding to @feetwet said, in some states the type of gun you can transfer varies.

Comment: FWIW, the method of production is completely irrelevant in the eyes of the law as StephenG's answer demonstrates.  Also, not all parts of a typical firearm for a standard chambering are capable of being 3D printed.

Answer (score 5):

Bob can probably print the firearm for personal ownership if Bob is not prohibited from possessing a firearm himself, but after that it gets problematic.  This is ignoring any potential safety violations and liability issues or patent violations which might arise.

According to an ATF spokesman quoted in [this article](https://freebeacon.com/issues/atf-explains-law-surrounding-3d-printed-guns/) :

> it is legal for Americans to build their own firearms without a license so long as they are not prohibited by law from possessing firearms, the firearms are legal to own, for personal use, and **not for sale or transfer to others**. Whether the gun parts are printed, created by other ways of manufacturing, or legally purchased from a licensed dealer has no impact on whether it is legal for an American to build a gun for personal use, though some states like California have placed additional requirements on the process.

So transfer of ownership is possibly problematic.

It's notably not a way to avoid normal firearm possession restrictions :

> Knight [the ATF spokesman]  emphasized it is not legal for felons or somebody otherwise prohibited from possessing firearms to build their own guns under any circumstance.

> "Title 18 of the United States Code, section 922(g) prohibits several categories of persons (i.e., persons convicted of a crime punishable by imprisonment for more than a year) from possessing firearms in or affecting interstate commerce," Knight said. "Title 18 of the Unites States Code, section 922(d) prohibits persons from disposing of any firearm to a person the transferor has reason to believe is prohibited from possessing firearms under federal law."

Finally there's a rather crucial point to note about the design of such firearms :

> He said the Undetectable Firearms Act of 1988 outlaws the manufacture or possession of firearms that can pass through a walk-through metal detector or X-ray machine commonly employed at airports without being detected.

> "A person or manufacturer cannot produce an undetectable firearm as prescribed in Title 18 of the United States Code, section 922(p)," he said.

So making a weapon that's undetectable by a metal detector is not allowed (at least according to the ATF).

Answer (score 0):

### in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), private manufacture is banned anyway

To manufacture any firearms, you already need certification as a gunsmith in Germany. Because a gunsmith has to register any gun they make and sell, as well as having to undergo *Beschuss* (*proof*) for any firearm  to show it is safe, the [laws did not have to be changed at all](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/waffen-dreiddrucker-100.html):

- It is illegal to make 3D-printed firearms at home because that is manufacturing firearms without a license.
- As the quality of 3D printed weapons generally is poor, they can't manage to gain proof marks after having shown their suitability at a proofing test and not gain the proof mark.
- A firearm without a proof mark can not legally be sold.
- The shape and color of a firearm or its accessories may not give the weapon the appearance of a toy or any other item. If it does, it is an illegal concealed weapon. Examples of such banned items are belt-buckles, shooting canes or pen-guns, but also a "hello Kitty" themed hunting rifle or many pure-plastic 3D printed guns.

Relatedly, the sale or gifting of firearms is regulated and requires a registration of the transfer. The receiver of the firearm needs to have a weapon ownership card.

The same principle applies to accessories that are not defined as an integral part of the weapon: they are treated as what they are. Custom grip panels or mounting hardware are unregulated, while silencers are regulated for hunters only while targeting lasers or firearm-mounted lights are illegal in any shape or form - no matter if those are 3D printed or otherwise made.